# Objc Object Dealloc Memory Management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

If I have an object called Catalog that has a (nonatomic, retain) attrib called "title". I do "[attrib release];" in the dealloc method of Catalog:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [title release], title = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Later I do "Catalog *c = [Catalog new];".

Compare **1:**

dto.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"...", ...];

and **2:**

dto.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...",...];

It is common sense to release all attribs of an object in the dealloc method, but what if I pass along an accessor method (that already has an autorelease)? Should I release or not release the accessor'd attribute in dealloc then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your setter for `title` retains the string, so it needs to be released in -dealloc. Your first case is just wrong... you're calling +alloc followed by +stringWithFormat:. I suspect you mean -initWithFormat:. Also, you need to release the string there because you're alloc'ing it. It's ugly and unreliable to call -release on a property, so it's common to use a temporary variable for this sort of thing:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:...];
dto.title = string;
[string release];
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but it could be better, since using +stringWithFormat: avoids the need for a temp variable.

Comment: I was addressing the first case from the question. The second case uses +stringWithFormat, and I agree that there's no need for the temp variable there because there's no need to release the string. Edited answer slightly to make that less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If the accessor already has an autorelease, then don't release it again in dealloc. The new+copy+alloc count must match the release+autorelease count.

Comment: The -release in -dealloc matches the retain from the property.

Comment: The lifespan of something autoreleased is such that an autoreleased object can never safely be the value of an instance variable.  I.e. the implication of that first sentence is entirely wrong;  if it is an instance variable, it should be retained or explicitly described as weak.  Whether it is autoreleased or not isn't a part of the discussion.

Comment: @bbum If he autoreleases some time after an alloc, then he should not release it again in the dealloc method.  I'm not saying that using autorelease in that case is a good idea, I'm just answering the question as it was asked.

Comment: With that clarification, down vote removed.   Seen too many people trip over assigning autorelease'd object to ivars with some goofy "but I'll make sure it is only used during this pass through even loop" mantra.